# Identifying PDF Layers

Tags: python, python-2.7, pdf, pypdf

I am trying to write a Python script that reads PDFs and Identifies whether they have additional layers added to them or not. 
I can't seem to find any documentation about whether it's possible or not on the internet so I thought i'd just ask.

If you could let me know a function or a module that reads the PDF and identifies whether it has layers on the PDF that would be great!

Thanks.

Comment: Python is a Turing-complete language and the ISO specifications for PDF are readily available, so I'd eyeball this as "*definitely* possible". Even if a certain library 'only' allows read basic access at the object level -- an impressive feat on itself --, you can use that to determine if a file has layers.